# PySpark Job to analyse sales data

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to write a Spark Job in python. I have two csv files containing following information:

File-1) product_prices.csv

`product1    10`

`product2    20`

```
product3    30
```

File-2 Sales_information.csv

```
id  buyer   transaction_date    seller  sales_data
1   buyer1  2015-1-01   seller1 {"product1":12,"product2":44}
2   buyer2  2015-1-01   seller3 {"product2":12}
3   buyer1  2015-1-01   seller3 {"product3":60,"product1":42}
4   buyer3  2015-1-01   seller2 {"product2":9,"product3":2}
5   buyer3  2015-1-01   seller1 {"product2":8}
```

Now, on above two files of data, I want to execute Spark job to find two things and have the data outputed to csv file

1) Total sales for each seller needs to be outputted to total_sellers_sales.csv file as

```
`seller_id  total_sales`
`seller1        1160`
```

2) Ouput buyers list for each seller to sellers_buyers_list.csv as follows:

```
seller_id   buyers
seller1     buyer1, buyer3
```

So can anyone tell me what is the correct way to do it to write a Spark job.

Note: I need a code in python

Comment: you need to read both files into dataframes, explode the sales_data column of Sales_information.csv dataframe, join both dataframes with products, groupBy seller and sum the amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my pyspark code in zeppelin 0.7.2.
First I created your sample dataframes manually:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *                 
from pyspark.sql import functions as F                        

products = [ ("product1", 10),  ("product2",20),  ("product3",30)] 
dfProducts = sqlContext.createDataFrame(products, ['product', 'price'])                

sales = [ (1,"buyer1", "seller1","product1",12), (1,"buyer1", "seller1","product2",44), (2,"buyer2", "seller3","product2",12),(3,"buyer1", "seller3","product3",60),(3,"buyer1", "seller3","product1",42),(4,"buyer3", "seller2","product2",9),(4,"buyer3", "seller2","product3",2),(5,"buyer3", "seller1","product2",8)]                                          
dfSales= sqlContext.createDataFrame(sales, ['id', 'buyer', 'seller','product','countVal'])
```

Total sales for each seller:

```
dfProducts.alias('p').join(dfSales.alias('s'),col('p.product')==col('s.product')).groupBy('s.seller').agg(F.sum(dfSales.countVal * dfProducts.price)).show()
```

Output:
[Total sales for each seller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Hyhs.png):

Buyers list for each seller:

```
dfSales.groupBy("seller").agg(F.collect_set("buyer")).show()
```

Output: [Buyers list for each seller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFtQe.png)

You can save results as csv using df.write.csv('filename.csv') method.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, for answering my query for Apache Spark. Can you please also let me know how we can do the same thing by creating Google Data Flow Job? Can you please provide me the steps for it?

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48238741/google-dataflow-job

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any experience with Google Data Flow